# Refund using Razorpay in Node js

Tags: node.js, e-commerce, payment-gateway, mern, razorpay

I am building a shopping cart (using MERN stack and Razorpay payment gateway), where users can purchase items after adding them into cart. If more then one items would have purchased, razorpay generates a single paymentId for that purchase. And at the time of refund, the paymentId needs to be passed to the backend. Like this:

```
var instance = new Razorpay({ key_id: 'YOUR_KEY_ID', key_secret: 'YOUR_SECRET' })

instance.payments.refund(paymentId,{
  "amount": "100",
  "speed": "normal",
  "notes": {
    "notes_key_1": "Beam me up Scotty.",
    "notes_key_2": "Engage"
  },
  "receipt": "Receipt No. 31"
})
```

But if the user wants to get refund for only one item, then rest of the items with same paymentId, are getting refunded as well. So how to get refund for one item and the rest keeping intact?

I have tried to generate different orderId for each item, but at the end same paymentId id generated after successful payment. I want to get separate orderId and paymentId for each item and storing these in MongoDB

Comment: To process separate refunds for individual items while keeping the rest intact, you need to handle the payments and refunds at the item level rather than the order level. This means generating a separate paymentId and orderId for each item in the cart.

Comment: @PrashantLuhar If more than 1 items are purchased from cart, then a single paymentId gets auto generated for these items. Even if I generate separate paymentId, it won't get reflected in Razorpay dashboard. And eventually at the time of refund, it'll throw error as both paymentIds will mismatch.